# AutoMapper & .NET Core: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Today I have ran into an issue which I haven't been able to solve for the past hours. I have created a GitHub Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/mhagendoorn-9292/53b3a7bc5d45baa8394d4ee08fa0ecea) which shows my code. The error that AutoMapper has been returning is the following:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
> Mapping types:
> Object -> Order
> System.Object -> Rig.Commercial.Reservation.DataStorage.Entities.Order

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please, post the [mre] in the question itself, not on external links.

Comment: I think it could be a missing registration of your configuration. Try `services.AddAutoMapper(config => config.AddProfile(typeof(BookingsMappers)))`

Comment: @mu88 I guess he wants to use dependency injection

Comment: @Dominik Sure, this line must be added to `ConfigureServices()`

Comment: @mu88 That's where the RegisterAutoMapper(); method is being called from. I've tried your answer, but that doesn't really work unfortunatly.

Comment: When debugging, are you entering the `BookingsMappers` constructor?

Comment: @mu88 Yes! It actually is entering the ctor, that's why I'm so lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way you constructed your Profile class is wrong. That is `BookingsMappers` class in your code.

According to the [documentation here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html). The fix might be replacing your `BookingsMappers` class to like this:

```
public class BookingsMappers : Profile
{
    public BookingsMappers()
    {
        CreateMap<CreateBooking, Order>()
            .BeforeMap((createBooking, order) => order.Created = DateTime.Now)
            .BeforeMap((createBooking, order) => order.Modified = DateTime.Now)
            .BeforeMap((createBooking, order) => order.InternalId = Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```